# How can I get the number of empty lines using the LineNumberReader?

Tags: java, parsing, newline

I am trying to use the LineNumberReader to get the number of empty lines in a file. However I cannot manage to get such information. the following is the code that I am using

```
LineNumberReader reader  = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(this.file));
int cnt = 0;
String lineRead = "";
while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if(lineRead.length == 0){
    cnt++;
  }
}

reader.close();
System.out.println(cnt);
```

Does anyone know of how to be able to get such information ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680588/java-count-empty-lines-in-a-text-file-string

Comment: I would alter that to `if(lineRead.trim().length == 0){`

Comment: @Carlo I've tried that but its still returning 0, as if no empty lines are there when in fact there are

Comment: @Carlo  Even though it is a question with no answer, the [1st reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4680650/418556) contains a good strategy (repeating what I suggested in a comment).

Comment: my guess is that the line 'lineRead.length == 0' never evaluates to true. Add a printline before the if-statement too see what readLine returns when it's empty

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson That, or a debugger, would be very helpful at this stage.  Note that things are more clear with `System.out.println("'" + lineRead + "'");`.  That way, things like extra spaces and tab characters become more clear.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, it's a question withoun an answer, but like you said it give some different examples on how to deal with the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, Ive tried it with the buffer reader and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
if(lineRead.isEmpty()){
```

or

```
if(lineRead.trim().isEmpty()){
```

if you consider empty a line that contains only spaces or tabs